# django work with a Thermal Printer in Raspberry PI

Tags: python, linux, django, printing, raspberry-pi

I have a website in django, I only going to  visit the website using a Raspberry Pi,  I need print a data, and for print I am using a Thermal Printer in the Raspberry Pi.
I can print from the Raspberry pi using

**("/dev/ttyAMA0",19200,timeout=5)**

for obtain serial communication
This work fine  but only when the project is hosting local in the raspberry Pi , but the django project is hosting in a VPS with ubuntu  then I have problems for printer from the Raspberry PI.
because in ubuntu there are not

"/dev/ttyAMA0"

How I can work with this thermal Printer  from a django project for print  correctly using a RaspberryPi

Answer (score 0):

install a print server on the pi and serve the printer. you may need some sort of tunnel so that the VPS can reach the pi.